# Redirect IP address to domain name

Tags: redirect

Not sure how it happened, but Google has indexed my site both by IP address and domain name
and in some search in Google I see my site like `121.12.12.123/tech/tech.php`.

Please let me know how can I redirect it to my domain?

```
121.12.12.123    redirect to   www.mydomain.com
121.12.12.123/*  redirect to   www.mydomain.com/*
```

Comment: I have a feeling the right way to accomplish this is through server configuration

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your site is running on a apache webserver, you could use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and put something like this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^121\.12\.12\.123
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You can also use RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mydomain.com to redirect access through any host that's not your desired domain to your desired domain. This is a catch-all case.

Comment: @Gryphius; thanks a lot for your help,thanks also for marklu.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full htaccess for laravel to redirect from IP to Domain

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^5\.129\.317\.421$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```