# Google bots index both site ip and domain

Tags: drupal, redirect, drupal-6, ip, googlebot

It is a strange thing that google index both my site ip and domain at the same time. I read lots of think about that but I could'nt find any satisfying answer. I have two question about that:

1- How can I redirect my indexed ip pages to domain? Example:

```
http://myip/testpage.html               to
http://www.mydomain.com/testpage.html
```

2- Is it bad for seo and can cause to duplicate content? If I fix it can it affect my seo positively?

Answer (score 0):

1. This is just a server configuration issue. If you are on apache you can [redirect the IP address to the domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880903/redirect-ip-address-to-domain-name)
2. Short answer yes. Duplicate content is bad business, because search engines don't show duplicates and have to decide which version is the original one. There is a really nice article that goes into great detail on this subject: [What is Duplicate Content?](http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/duplicate-content)