# IP Address Redirect to URL when visited in browser

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

When a user visits my sites IP address in a web browser, I'd like to have it redirect to the site's main page (or redirect to a page I choose). I'm not sure if this is possible but we had basically set up a site on a temp URL (it was http://{IP_ADDRESS}/{SUBDIRECTORY}) and when it was ready we pointed the domain to the folder.

It works great but it was set in WordPress and some of the links were done using absolute paths so when people click on them, they go to the IP address and thus have a 404 error. We are obviously changing those links but the client wants any other ones to redirect to the homepage to be safe.

The server is a dedicated IP and I tried this in the .htaccess file (from: [Redirect IP address to domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880903/redirect-ip-address-to-domain-name)):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^121\.12\.12\.123
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I put in my credentials as well. It did not work.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^121\.12\.12\.123$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Ensure mod_rewrite is on.